# Cannot display variable value after retrieve from URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i'm new in javascript and i've a problem with my script. i'm trying to display a variable named **ideal** to id called **weight** after retrieved data from URL, but it didn't work.
can anyone help me with this problem, i'm really appreciate it...

here is the javascript code

```
<script>
    function formSubmit()
    {
        document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        var x = document.getElementById("frm1");

    }
    function getUrlVars() {
            var vars = {};
            var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    var first = getUrlVars()["height"];
    if(first<100){
        alert("Sorry, your height is not available");
    }else{
        var ideal = ((first-100)-(0.1*(first-100)));
        //alert(ideal); 
    }
    function update(){
        document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML=ideal;

    }

    </script>
</head>
```

and here is the HTML

```
<!-- <div id="pg1" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content" style="background-color: whitesmoke; height: 480px;">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" style="padding-top: 100px;">
                    <center> <h1></h1></center>
                    <center><h4></h4></center>
                    <form id="frm1">
                    <label for="txt_val"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="height" id="txt_val" value=""  placeholder="160.5" required/>
                    <center><a href="#" data-inline="true" data-role="button" onclick="formSubmit()"></a></center>
                    <p id="weight" onclick="update()"></p>
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"></div>
            </div>

        </div> -->
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it didn't work? Did you see any errors or problems occurring or did it just fail quietly?

Comment: thanks for response..
i didn't see any errors, it did just fail quitely. and i don't know how to fix it...
the variable **ideal** didn't display, even though i've already called the id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, where you are defining your variable **ideal** is in a local scope that can not be adapted to  your function **update**.

You can define it just after the global variable **first** and give it value at your current place.

Comment: thanks for the response. 
i've tried to put the variable **ideal** after the variable **first**
`var first = getUrlVars()["height"];
var ideal = ((first-100)-(0.1*(first-100)));
        if(first<100){
            alert("Sorry, your height is not available");
        }else{
            
            //alert(ideal); 
        }
        function update(){
            document.getElementById("weight").innerHTML=ideal;
    
        }` 

but it still didn't work...

Comment: Hi @user1972311, don't forget to mark this answer correct if it worked for you, as it might be useful to others. I'm sure tech_me would appreciate it too ;-)